# How do I do a Perl regex that matches everything after a backslash and before a certain file extension?

Tags: regex, perl

"..\directory\[filename].xml"

How would I go about a writing a regex that matches the above string with the quotes included? How do I match up to the .xml?

So far I've got the following. Not sure how to proceed after this, I'm pretty new to Perl.

```
$content =~ m/"..\\directory\\/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that [filename] is a variable value that you will fill in or do you want to extract the file name?  Or do you want to literally match that string?  Could you put a before and after example?

Comment: @lordadmira I wanted to extract the filename. So I'd give it something like "..\directory\a_file.xml" and I would get back "a_file.xml". I know File::Basename does this, but I needed the regex for other purposes. I achieved it with the following regex `/\"..\\directory\\(.*\.xml)\"/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method 1 (using regexes)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path = "..\\directory\\somefile.xml";

if(my ($before) = $path =~ m{^(.*)\.xml$}) {
    print "[$before] match!\n";
} else {
    print "no match!\n";
};
```

Output:

```
[..\directory\somefile] match!
```

### Method 2 (using [File::Spec::Win32](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Spec))

This method makes use of the built-in module File::Spec that comes with every Perl distribution.

This can be better than the first method because it's a specialized module for handling paths.

The built-in module [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) is also worth looking at.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec::Win32;

my $path = "..\\directory\\somefile.xml";
my ($volume,$directories,$file) = File::Spec::Win32->splitpath($path);

print "vol=$volume\n";
print "dirs=$directories\n";
print "file=$file\n";
```

Output:

```
vol=
dirs=..\directory\
file=somefile.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal regex for matching the base name component is this.

`m{([^\\/]+)$}`

In your case you would modify that a little like this.

`m{([^\\/]+\.xml)"$}`